# Using R lapply on a list to remove elements from the list

Tags: r, performance, loops, functional-programming, lapply

I have a list I want to process to remove elements not meeting certain criteria. I'd use a loop but that is too slow so I assume lapply might be better.

assuming the last thing function y does is give a value of 1 or 2 to variable x how would I modify

lapply(list,functiony, z=valueA, a=valueB) to give back a list of only the elements of the list that are of value x=1?

Comment: Please show some example data and your expected results.  It is not clear what `functiony` is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Maybe you could start showing us how you would proceed with a loop tp clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Try `mylist[sapply(mylist, functiony, z=valueA, a=valueB)==1]`